# Кто подскажет, как сделать вывод на экран такой же таблицы как в MySQL?

Tags: java, консоль, форматирование

[image: Вывод в консоль SQL таблицы]

Нужно, что бы в java сохранялась в файл подобная таблица. Мои жалкие потуги не продвинулись дальше вот этого:

```
Имя класса: ru.java2016.weekend1.task_1.SimpleBin
--------------------------------------------------
имя поля                    значение                    тип поля
----------------------------------------------------------------------
var                     13                      int
field                       El Diablo                       String
num                     666                     int
peee                        3.14                        double
e                       2.7                     double
emotion                     Bingo!                      String
luck                        777                     int
calibre                     7.62                        double
```

Криво/косо!!! Капец!
Собсно код:

```
public void printBody(Object object, Class clazz, String file, List<Field> list) {

    try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file))) {   // записываем в файл

        output.print("Имя класса:\t" + clazz.getName() + "\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) output.print("-");
        output.println("\nимя поля\t\t\t\t\tзначение\t\t\t\t\tтип поля");
        for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++) output.print("-");
        output.println();

        for (Field field : list) {

            // Выводим имя поля
            output.print(field.getName() + "\t\t\t\t\t\t");

            // Выводим значение поля
            field.setAccessible(true);  // !!! разрешить доступ к значениям полей !!!
            output.print(field.get(object) + "\t\t\t\t\t\t");

            // Выводим тип поля
            if (field.getType().toString().equals("class java.lang.String")) output.println("String");
            else output.println(field.getType().toString());
        }
    } catch (Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Эпидерсия какая-то! Может у кого есть опыт создания подобных таблиц?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `printf()` и указывайте ему длину поля

```
output.println("%-20s%-10s%-10s%n", "имя поля", "значение", "тип поля");
..............
for (Field field : list) {
  // Выводим имя поля
  output.printf("%-20s", field.getName());
  // Выводим значение поля
  field.setAccessible(true);  // !!! разрешить доступ к значениям полей !!!
  output.printf("%10s", field.get(object));
 // Выводим тип поля
 if (field.getType().toString().equals("class java.lang.String"))
   output.println("String");
 else
   output.println(field.getType().toString());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось!!!